# Defining Images Taken using the iOS camera Adobe Air

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, camera, adobe

So, I'm working on an app that uses the camera in Adobe Air & Actionscript 3.0, I know the CameraUI, etc, but I'm just having problems with defining the image that is taken using the camera so I can bitmapData and all that jazz, here is my code

```
import flash.media.CameraUI;



var cameraUI:CameraUI = new CameraUI();

if (CameraUI.isSupported ) 
{
    cameraUI.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE, imageSelected); 
    cameraUI.addEventListener(MediaEvent.ERROR, imageError);
    cameraUI.addEventListener(MediaEvent.CANCEL, imagecancelled);
    cameraUI.launch(MediaType.IMAGE); 
}
```

So, is there anyway to define the image taken using the camera.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraUI.html#includeExamplesSummary

**EDIT**

[My Camera code for a mobile app]

```
package com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.tools 
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.MediaEvent;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.media.CameraUI;
    import flash.media.MediaPromise;
    import flash.media.MediaType;

    public class CameraTool extends ToolBase implements ITool
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Variables
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private var deviceCameraApp:CameraUI = new CameraUI();
        private var imageLoader:Loader; 

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Constructor
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public function CameraTool(stage:Stage) {
            super(stage);

            if( CameraUI.isSupported )
            {
                trace( "Initializing camera..." );

                deviceCameraApp.addEventListener( MediaEvent.COMPLETE, imageCaptured );
                deviceCameraApp.addEventListener( Event.CANCEL, captureCanceled );
                deviceCameraApp.addEventListener( ErrorEvent.ERROR, cameraError );
            }
            else
            {
                trace( "Camera interface is not supported.");
            }
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Handlers
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public function takeAction(event:TouchEvent=null):void
        {
            model.disableNextAutosave = true;
            deviceCameraApp.launch( MediaType.IMAGE );
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Camera UI functions
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private function imageCaptured( event:MediaEvent ):void
        {
            trace( "Media captured..." );

            var imagePromise:MediaPromise = event.data;

            if( imagePromise.isAsync )
            {
                trace( "Asynchronous media promise." );
                imageLoader = new Loader();
                imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, asyncImageLoaded );
                imageLoader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cameraError );

                imageLoader.loadFilePromise( imagePromise );
            }
            else
            {
                trace( "Synchronous media promise." );
                imageLoader.loadFilePromise( imagePromise );
                showMedia( imageLoader );
            }
        }

        private function captureCanceled( event:Event ):void
        {
            trace( "Media capture canceled." );
        }

        private function asyncImageLoaded( event:Event ):void
        {
            trace( "Media loaded in memory." );
            showMedia( imageLoader );    
        }

        private function showMedia( loader:Loader ):void
        {
            loader.scaleX=-1;
            layerM.addLayer( loader );
        }

        private function cameraError( error:ErrorEvent ):void
        {
            trace( "Error:" + error.text );
        }

        public function toString():String
        {
            return "Loading CameraUI";
        }

    }
}
```

Here's an example from my project:
https://github.com/wafflejock/FingerPainting/blob/master/FlashBuilderProject/FingerPainting/src/com/shaunhusain/fingerPainting/tools/CameraTool.as

Demo/Shameless self promotion:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.chitowngames.DigitalDoodler

You can change what happens in the showMedia function with regard to the loader.  So if you want access to the BitmapData, in there just do:

```
(loader.content as Bitmap).bitmapData
```

Comment: I know this, but is there an easier solution to just defining the image taken even before it is taken?

Comment: @user1666767 that doesn't really make any sense to me?  I believe it's left up to the OS to actually save the image to memory (you have no control over this as far as I know).  It then gives you a handle to resolve/load that reference from the memory.  This is as easy as it can get so far as I can tell.  After the loader has the Bitmap in it's content you can extract the BitmapData.

Comment: Is it possible you could write it yourself because I don't really understand what you're saying?

Comment: I pasted code I'm actually using in an app.  Let me know if you still have questions, this allows you to capture an image from the camera then load it.  In my case I'm just passing it along to a LayerManager class I made up to handle layers in an image editor, it in turn adds the BitmapData to the stage.